# handling multiple errors in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

I have a method in Node JS which reads a file containing JSON data and finds a product with specific ID.

```
async getProductwithId(id) {
        try {
            let rawData = fs.readFileSync("data/products.json");
            let data = JSON.parse(rawData);
            for (const element of data) {
                if (id === element.productId) {
                    return element;
                }
            }
            throw new ProductDoesNotExistError("No Such Product Exists");
        } catch (error) {
            throw new FileReadingError("Error Reading File");
        }
    }
```

where ProductDoesNotExistError and FileReadingError both extend Error. I have put try/catch for the fs.readFileSync()

the problem is even if i have ProductDoesNotExistError, it's sending FileReadingError. I want to handle here the FileReadingError only and not ProductDoesNotExistError. I will let the callling function handle the ProductDoesNotExistError. How do I achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in your catch block you throw a new instance of `FileReadingError`, all caught errors will result in the latter. You could either put the `try/catch` just around the `readFileSync` operation or check the type of the error in your catch block (also there's no need for `async` as the code inside the method is not async - e.g. your not using `fs.promises.readFile()`):

```
getProductwithId(id) {
    let rawData;
    try {
        rawData = fs.readFileSync("data/products.json");
    } catch (error) {
        throw new FileReadingError("Error Reading File");
    }
    const data = JSON.parse(rawData);
    for (const element of data) {
        if (id === element.productId) {
            return element;
        }
    }
    throw new ProductDoesNotExistError("No Such Product Exists");
}
```

or you do:

```
getProductwithId(id) {
    try {
        const rawData = fs.readFileSync("data/products.json");
        const data = JSON.parse(rawData);
        for (const element of data) {
            if (id === element.productId) {
                return element;
            }
        }
        throw new ProductDoesNotExistError("No Such Product Exists");
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof ProductDoesNotExistError) {
            // rethrow ProductDoesNotExistError error
            throw error;
        }
        throw new FileReadingError("Error Reading File");
    }
}
```